# Always feel like somebody watching me

Tags: support

I answered a question, got a "not so good" comment from a user that answered the same question.Then in less that 24 hours, I got 4 times x (-1) in other of my answers.
What should be the appropriate steps?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked through the logs and found no evidence that a user involved in the question, answers or comments have performed downvotes. In fact I found that one participant also got downvoted at the time you got downvotes. Why this is, is hard to tell.

Often I find that rep changes upward also comes in chunks where users tend to upvota other answers as well. Hopefully this isn't a case of stalking you alone, but a single event from a user having a really bad day.

While awaiting futher actions (if needed) take the advice from [Rockwell - Somebody's Watching Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YvAYIJSSZY)

;-)

Feel free to monitor this issue and contact us again if you feel someone doesn't live up to community rules.

Comment: One more q: Is it the same user that has downvoted me all 5 (now) times?

Comment: @XristosK I couldn't find evidence of that, no